# Accessing data of different layers in Costmap2DROS

Tags: navigation, c++, costmap, move-base, costmap-2d

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to access the data of the internal `master_grid` of the `obstacle_layer`. I am working in another layer and right now I am reading the values out of the `layered_costmap_`, which works fine like that:

```
  costmap_2d::Costmap2D* costmap = layered_costmap_->getCostmap();
```

Also, if I would be within the `obstacle_layer`, I would access the data of its own `master_grid` like that:

```
  unsigned char* master_array = master_grid.getCharMap();
```

But how would I access the `master_grid` of the `obstacle_layer` from another layer? Thanks!

---

UPDATE:

I think I found a working piece of code which answers like 95 % of my question. So the code searches through all the layers of the `COSTMAP` (actually it is a layered costmap of type `costmap_2d::Costmap2DROS`) and operates on the one which matches a predefined string (`layer_sear_string_`). But can somebody help me how to find the name of the layered costmap `global_planner` when running move_base?

```
std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<costmap_2d::Layer> >* plugins = COSTMAP->getLayeredCostmap()->getPlugins();

for (std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<costmap_2d::Layer> >::iterator pluginp = plugins->begin(); pluginp != plugins->end(); ++pluginp) {

    boost::shared_ptr<costmap_2d::Layer> plugin = *pluginp;

    if(plugin->getName().find(layer_search_string_)!=std::string::npos) {
        boost::shared_ptr<costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer> costmap;
        costmap = boost::static_pointer_cast<costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer>(plugin);
        unsigned char* grid = costmap->getCharMap();
        
        // do sth with it
        
    }
}
```

Code found [here](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/hydro-devel/clear_costmap_recovery/src/clear_costmap_recovery.cpp).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/172670/accessing-data-of-different-layers-in-costmap2dros/) by [Luke_ROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/15276/luke_ros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 116 on 2014-06-03

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2014-06-13**:
Can you clarify your updated question? Which name are you looking for?

**Comment by [Luke_ROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/15276/luke_ros/) on 2014-06-17**:
When running move_base you get a global_planner and a local_planner. Both of them should be of type costmap_2d::Costmap2DROS, right? So I am looking for a way to access the top layered costmap of the global_planner from within a layer. (In order to finally access the master_grid of another layer).

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2014-06-17**:
To clarify terminology: In move_base, there is a global planner and a local planner, which operate on the global costmap and local costmap respectively (both of which are Costmap2DROS). I believe you are looking for a way to access the layered costmap object of the global costmap...

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2014-06-17**:
...so that you can access an individual layer's private costmap.

(There is no such thing as a "top layered costmap" and the layered costmap has a master costmap, but the individual layers aren't referred to as master costmaps.)

**Comment by [Luke_ROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/15276/luke_ros/) on 2014-06-17**:
Yes. That's spot on. Sorry. I got confused by the different terminologies of the paper and the actual code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Within any layer, you can access the layered costmap object via

```
protected:
    LayeredCostmap* layered_costmap_;
```

You can use that object to get a particular layer with the code you linked above.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2014-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Luke_ROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/15276/luke_ros/) on 2014-06-26**:
Thanks a lot. Your answer led me on the right path again. I simply needed to replace COSTMAP->getLayeredCostmap() with the layered_costmap_ since we still operate within the same Costmap2DROS structure. Problem solved. Many things learned.

**Comment by [aswin](https://answers.ros.org/users/212/aswin/) on 2015-01-09**:
@Luke_ROS Did you get the above to work? I dont see a getCharMap() in costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer

**Comment by [aswin](https://answers.ros.org/users/212/aswin/) on 2015-01-09**:
Updated [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/200646/access-obstaclelayer-costmap2d-in-localplanner/?answer=200649#post-id-200649). Just need to replace ObstacleLayer with costmap_2d::CostmapLayer